# combining strings from rows in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run statistical tests on strings from a  large corpus (1 million + records) and I am not sure how best to do this in mySQL directly rather than parsing it in php, which would take (me at least based on my skills) ages.

The table:

```
ID              Words
----------      -------------
1               ham
2               cheese
3               lettuce
4               tomato
5               onion
```

The desired output I am trying to achieve is to create two new columns containing bigrams and trigrams of each strings as follow:

```
ID              Words            Bigrams           Trigrams
----------      -------------    -------------     -------------
1               ham              ham_cheese        ham_cheese_lettuce
2               cheese           cheese_lettuce    cheese_lettuce_tomato
3               lettuce          lettuce_tomato    lettuce_tomato_onion
4               tomato           tomato_onion      ........
5               onion            .........         ........
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this in mySQL?

Comment: Should these always consist of ID & ID+1 & ID+2, or are you looking for *all permutations*?

Comment: @Kaii it would always be ID, +1, +2

Comment: Have tried  with  join ?  we can help you  to improve your query ... if you try ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, no i have not. i have used join before in joining two tables but would not know how to use it in this case. would you mind suggesting how this could be applied?

Comment: Join one or more table is pratically the same  .. in this case you should (my idea)  join the same table using alias 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to accomplish this, would be with a self join. If the tables name would be *all_words* with fields *id* and *word*:

```
SELECT
    first.id, 
    first.word, 
    CONCAT(first.word, '_', second.word) AS bigram, 
    CONCAT(first.word, '_', second.word, '_', third.word) AS trigram
FROM
    all_words first
LEFT JOIN
    all_words second ON first.id + 1 = second.id
LEFT JOIN
    all_words third ON first.id + 2 = third.id
```

With the concat() function you concatenate the words from the different tables into one column. If you'd want the bigram and trigram column to be empty for the last rows (instead of only the first words), use

```
IF(second.word IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(first.word, '_', second.word), '') AS bigram
```

for the bigram and something equal for the trigram.

Comment: Note:  This solution relies on subsequently incremented IDs without any gaps.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'd like to be able to give you feedback soon but the query is still running and it looks like it will take a while. Thanks again and I'll let you know if it worked ;)

Comment: @Jacob To test if it works you should add `LIMIT 100` to the query. Your current query does this calculation for all rows - of course it will take a while to deliver millions of rows to your client.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating an array in php should be much faster than doing it in mysql, but to get your result from the database you have to use a `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.words, 
       concat(t1.words, '_', t2.words) as Bigrams
       concat(t1.words, '_', t2.words, '_', t3.words) as Trigrams
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2
on t2.id = t1.id + 1 
left join tablename t2
on t3.id = t1.id + 2
```

Comment: Note:  This solution relies on subsequently incremented IDs without any gaps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm testing the suggested join but the query is taking a while

Comment: @Jacob Yes it will take a while. As I said, doing array manipulation in php is faster, mysql will now have to do the joins and it takes time to retrieve 3 times the amount of data from the database. (And I assume you have `id` as the primary key, otherwise this would be really really slow).

Comment: @Solarflare, thanks. I initially stayed clear of arrays in PHP as I thought the size of the query would be significant and the array would in turn be slow but I might give that a try given how slow this is turning out to be (and yes I have primary key). Good to know it and how it can be done in sql though

Answer (score 1):

Ya can perform multiple `join` on the same table and keep the logic if `ID+1`

```
select mytable.id, mytable.value                                Words
     , concat(mytable.value,'_',bigram.value)                   bigrams
     , concat(mytable.value,'_',bigram.value,'_',trigram.value) trigrams
from mytable 
left join mytable bigram  on (mytable.id + 1 = bigram.id)
left join mytable trigram on (mytable.id + 2 = trigram.id)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm testing the suggested join but the query is taking a while